# Modal To Page-Based Layout Stalls WatchKit App

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I've been trying for a bit of time now to figure out an issue in my WatchKit app, and am hoping someone may have some insight.

Initially, I built my app as a hierarchical navigation layout, wherein my initial View Controller shows a table that is populated with some data, and a user can tap a cell and be "pushed" to a detail Interface Controller with more contextual information (data is being gathered as JSON data and passed from the iOS app via Shared App Groups).

According to the developer documentation, it's not possible to mix a hierarchical and page-based layout, unless a modal is involved.  Ideally, I'd like a user to tap a cell in my initial table, have a modal pop-up, and then have multiple pages the user can flip through that have detailed information based on which cell they chose.

For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to make this work.  If there is no page-based layout involved, the app works fine.  The user taps a cell, a modal pops up, and proper contextual information is display.  If I add a new Interface Controller and segue with a nextPage from my modal, no contextual information is passed and any commands cease to run.  If I delete my nextPage segue, the app returns to running fine.

Here is my **InterfaceController.swift** file;

```
import WatchKit

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {
var minions = [Minion]()

@IBOutlet weak var minionTable: WKInterfaceTable!

let defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName:
    "group.com.mygroup.data")

override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)

    //Load the table
    reloadTable()

    //Get the data passed from the iOS app
    WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication(["request": "refreshData"], reply: { (replyInfo, error) -> Void in
        if let minionData = replyInfo["minionData"] as? NSData {
            NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(Minion.self, forClassName: "Minion")
            if let minions = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(minionData) as? [Minion] {
                self.minions = minions
                self.reloadTable()
            }
            println("dataTest: \(self.minions)")
        }
    })
}



func reloadTable() {

    if minionTable.numberOfRows != minions.count {
        minionTable.setNumberOfRows(minions.count, withRowType: "MinionTableRowController")
    }

    for (index, minion) in enumerate(minions) {
        if let row = minionTable.rowControllerAtIndex(index) as? MinionTableRowController {

            row.interfaceGroup.setBackgroundColor(UIColor(red: 39.0/255.0, green: 148.0/255.0, blue: 197.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0))
            row.interfaceLabel.setText(minion.name)

            row.interfaceDetails.setText("\(age!) years old")
        }
    }
}

override func contextForSegueWithIdentifier(segueIdentifier: String, inTable table: WKInterfaceTable, rowIndex: Int) -> AnyObject? {
    if segueIdentifier == "minionSegue" {
        let minion = minions[rowIndex]
        return minion
    }

    return nil
}



override func willActivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    super.willActivate()


    NSLog("%@ will activate", self)
}


//I have nothing to put here
override func didDeactivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
    NSLog("%@ did deactivate", self)
    super.didDeactivate()
}

}
```

I can provide more information as needed, but it seems as though passing data to multiple pages is different than passing data to one page.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What you're trying to accomplish is definitely doable. In fact, it's how my app works. Instead of using interface builder for your segues, try calling `presentControllerWithNames:contexts:` on `WKInterfaceController` to present your named interface controllers when someone selects a row. This is at least worth a quick experiment to see if this approach works for you.

Comment: Thanks, @MikeSwanson, I believe this is the right path to take.  Based on your suggestion, where in my InterfaceController.swift file would I place the `presentControllerWithNames:contexts:` command?  I've found some very helpful data online about how to perform this if I had a button that would lead to my next Interface Controller, but if my "button" is actually my table row?

Comment: You can implement the `table:didSelectRowAtIndex:` method on `WKInterfaceController` to detect a row tap. More here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/table:didSelectRowAtIndex:

Comment: Got it working!  Thank you @MikeSwanson!  I used the `table:didSelectRowAtIndex:` method, in conjunction with the `presentControllerWithNames:contexts:` to properly call my multiple pages in my controllers.  The data is now being passed properly!